# Angular 2 Materialize issue after routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an application with the https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize and am running into an issue after any kind of page routing. It seems that any kind of Materialism.js is not getting called at all after I change pages with:
    this.router.navigate(['xxxxx']. 
For me this doesn't work for a modal, the full screen image zoom, the tabs and the autocomplete. (but I suspect any materialize.js will not work)

As a added note: If I refresh the page that I have routed to, then the materialize.js features work as expected.

Updating with code sample

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}
...
// after this call is made, all materialize javascript features are lost on the resulting page
this.router.navigate(['/add', add.id]);
```

routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'add/:id',
    component: AddComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'first' },
      { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
      { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: If we loads every router page again, then the concept Single Page is not fulfilled here.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with the same situation, though managed to do a hack by reloading using jquery the whole page on routerLink Click

In your component

```
<a [routerLink]="['link2']" class="linkReload">
```

Create a js file and add the following code (add jquery)

```
 $('.linkReload').click(function () {
    location.reload();
  });
```

**NB** In case Angular show 404 error when reloading
import the bolow line into your app.module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

add this to providers in app.module.ts

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```